# Can GraphQL optionally resolve a field given result of a query in resolver?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql

I have the following REST endpoints:

> /orders/{id}

```
returns {
    orderId,
    orderItem,
    customerId
}
```

> /customers/{id}

```
returns {
   customerId,
   firstName,
   lastName
}
```

I am limited by these two endpoints, which are going to be wrapped in my graphql schema.

I would like the following Schema:

```
type Order {
  orderId: ID!,
  orderItem: String,
  customer: Customer
}

type Customer{
  customerId: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
}

type Query {
  getOrder(id: String!): Order,
  getCustomer(id: String!): Customer
}
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to have GraphQL resolve the Customer object in the Order type?  I understand that you cannot pass the result of a query into the parameter of another.

I have considered the resolver of `getOrder` be:

```
const getOrderResolver = axios.get(`/orders/${id}`)
  .then((ordersRes) => {
    let customerId;
    if(ordersRes.data.customerId !== null) {
      customerId = ordersRes.data.customerId 
      axios.get(`/customers/${customerId}`)
      .then((customerRes) => ({
        return {
          orderId: ordersRes.data.orderId
          orderItem: ordersRes.data.orderItem
          customer: {
            customerId: customerRes.data.customerId
            firstName: customerRes.data.firstName
            lastName: customerRes.data.lastName 
          }
        }
      })
    } else {
      return {
          orderId: ordersRes.data.orderId
          orderItem: ordersRes.data.orderItem
          customer: null
      }
    }
    })
  })
```

`getCustomer` resolver

```
const getCustomerResolver = axios.get(`/customers/${customerId}`)
          .then((customerRes) => ({
            return {
                customerId: customerRes.data.customerId
                firstName: customerRes.data.firstName
                lastName: customerRes.data.lastName 
            }
          })
```

It seems with my solution, there will be the additional cost of always fetching the `Customer` type whether or not it is queried within the `getOrder` query.  Is it possible to rewrite my GraphQL schema in a way that GraphQL would be able to resolve the `Customer` type only when queried?

The limitation of my given my `ORDERS` REST API only returns the `CustomerId`  makes it difficult to resolve in `getOrder`, since the `Customer` API requires a `customerId`

Comment: How are you building your schema? Are you calling the GraphQLSchema constructor directly or using a utility function like `buildSchema` or `makeExecutableSchema`? Or is the schema creation coupled with some other library you're using, like Apollo Server?

Comment: I am using `makeExecutableSchema` via `graphql-tools` and serving it via Apollo Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two things to keep in mind here:

- GraphQL won't resolve a field unless it's requested (i.e. your resolver will not be called unless the field is actually included in the request).
- Each resolver has access to the value its "parent" field resolved to.

So your `getOrder` resolver can only worry about returning an order object:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getOrder: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/orders/${args.id}`)
      return response.data
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Note that if the REST endpoint returns a response in the same "shape" as your field's type, there's no need to map the response data to your actual fields here -- just return `response.data`.

Now we can add a resolver for the `customer` field on our Order type:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: { ... },
  Order: {
    customer: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      if (!parent.customerId) {
        return null
      }
      const response = await axios.get('/customers/${parent.customerId}')
      return response.data
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Our parent field here will be `getOrder` (or any other field that has an `Order` type). The value of `parent` will be whatever value you returned in that field's resolver (or if you returned a Promise, whatever that Promise resolved to). So we can use `parent.customerId` for the call to the `/customers` endpoint and return the data from the response. And again, this resolver will only be called if the `customer` field is actually requested.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Works like a charm and is now saving me multiple API round trips after refactoring the backend!

Comment: Is it possible to define resolvers for childen of children? 

For example, how would you add another child resolver to `customer` when it is already a child of `Order`?

Comment: @Jim Every field has a type. If that type is an object type, you can define resolvers for any field on that type. So if `customer` has the type `Customer` and `Customer` is an object type, you can define resolvers for any field on `Customer`. The fact that `customer` is a field on `Order` is irrelevant.